# How do these two ES6 functions access "this" differently?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm curious why **functionA** returns an error while **functionB** has a correct reference to "this" and works. What is the reason for the difference?

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  ...

  render() {
    return (
      <input ref="myInput" type="text" />
      <button onClick={this.functionA} />
      <button onClick={this.functionB} />
    );
  }
}
```

This throws an error "Can't read property 'refs' of undefined:

```
functionA() {
  const val = this.refs.myInput.value;
  console.log(val); 
}
```

While this correctly shows the value:

```
functionB = () => {
  const val = this.refs.myInput.value;
  console.log(val); 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch)

Comment: The *reason* is that you are using different type of functions, whose main purpose is to resolve `this` differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In JavaScript function context is defined while calling the function, not while defining it.**

You pass both function as callbacks to other component. They are called outside of object they are defined. Thus, they do not share it's class context.

What makes difference here is definition of `functionB`. Using arrow function binds current context to underlying function.

You can read more here http://reactkungfu.com/2015/07/why-and-how-to-bind-methods-in-your-react-component-classes/
... or google more if you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two functions is the use of the arrow expression added on es6 that allow the use of lexycal this.

Until arrow functions, every new function defined its own `this` value, preventing you from accessing the correct value.
One of the common workaround is to define a reference to the this on the correct context level and the use it inside your function:

```
var that = this; //creating a reference to the this we will need in a function
that.refs.myInput.value; // in our function we refer to 'that' variable
```

Arrow functions instead capture the `this` value of the enclosing context, so the this you are referring in FunctionB is actually taken from the "correct" context.

for more information please check:
https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 0):

In traditional function declaration i.e. `function` keyword `this` inside function scope refer to the object to which the function belong , or `undefined` if there is no hosting object .The point is `function` form a new scope different from outside

In new `=>` syntax ,there is a different story .the function **do not** from the new scope (quite different the old way) ,rather,its scope is the same as the outside scope

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions